# Create a square Polygon from lower left corner coordinates

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I do have coordinates (lat, lon) and I need to create polygon of 100 meters.
For now I can only create a polygon (square) where the point is the center of it and not the lower left corner.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Point


# Generate some sample data 
p1 = Point((-122.431297, 37.773972))
points = gpd.GeoSeries([p1])

# Buffer the points using a square cap style
# Note cap_style: round = 1, flat = 2, square = 3
buffer = points.buffer(1, cap_style = 3)
```

Comment: In general, I'd recommend using geometric (projected), not geographic coordinates for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `geopy` to generate/construct the remaining points.

```
import geopy
import geopy.distance as distance
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

#Assume each site is 100m (question not clear)
d = distance.distance(kilometers=100/1000)

# Going clockwise, from lower-left to upper-left, upper-right...
p1 = geopy.Point(( 37.773972, -122.431297))
p2 = d.destination(point=p1, bearing=0)
p3 = d.destination(point=p2, bearing=90)
p4 = d.destination(point=p3, bearing=180)

points = [(p.latitude, p.longitude) for p in [p1,p2,p3,p4]]
polygon = Polygon(points)
```

Comment: Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot @PeterSmith 
Just quick question, so the distance of each side (of the square) is 100m, means that the square surface is a hectare ?

Comment: Yes, the example code uses 100m as each side's length which makes the area of the square 1 hectare.